# How can I make a GIS region an agent in anylogic?

Tags: gis, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

1. Is there any way to make a **GIS region** an agent? For example, In Arizona we have 15 counties. Can I make the individual county area an individual agent? In the tutorials it mentions how to place one agent in a GIS region but it's not mentioned how to make the whole GIS region an agent which can have it's own statechart.
2. (If 1st one can be done) Suppose there lives some **Person** agent on each of those GIS region area (county). Is there any way to move  those **Person** agent based on the state of the county agent? 
   In simple words, I want to move some **Person** agents from county "a" to another county "b" based on county's statechart. If I send msg or command to **Person** statechart, I have to make sure only those person agents living in the county "a" are getting the command to move. Is there any way to model that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 1 can be done, but not directly. Here is how:

- create an agent type "myGISRegion"
- place a parameter into it and change its type to "GISRegion", name it "p_MyGISRegion"
- when instantiating it on Main (or whereever), set the parameter to the GISRegion you like below

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I found that this way really helps in creating the whole region an agent.

Comment: However, This way I can create one single agent but I am actually facing the problem of multiple GISRegion agent creation. Is there any way to create multiple GISRegion agents?
I tried by putting all the county name in an excel file & importing as a database, but if I put the parameter type to "GISRegion", during model run it shows error. (I putagent instead of agent type).

If I put "agent type" for this GISregion database, then it doesn't create any agent population during run time. How I can solve this problem?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Well, create an agent population instead and set the p_MyGISRegion according to a function or similar (agent 1 gets GISRegion X, agent 2 gets region Y...). Check out some example models to see how agent populations  work :-)